# Getting MMIX repo for CVS/Git

Tags: git, cvs, mmix

How can you get [the CVS repo of MMIX](http://mmixmasters.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/mmixmasters/) to CVS/Git?

I know how to clone a repo at github by `git clone URL`, but I have never really used sourceforge before. They use CVS which is new to me.

My unsuccessful attempt

```
git cvs -d:pserver:anonymous@mmixmasters.cvs.sourceforge.net:/cvsroot/mmixmasters
```

I get the following tip at CVS -irc in trying to download the repo by CVS first

```
cvs -d /tmp/ add co -PA mixmasters
```

However, it is not working for me as expected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not clear what you expected that to do.  git is not magic that drives CVS, it's an entirely different thing altogether.

git does have a `cvsimport` tool that will make a git repository out of a CVS repository, but do note that this will be an entirely different thing.

An example import:

```
mkdir mmixmasters
cd mmixmasters
git cvsimport -d:pserver:anonymous@mmixmasters.cvs.sourceforge.net:/cvsroot/mmixmasters mmixmasters
```

I'd recommend you understand both git and cvs better before trying to work with one gating the other, though.